# Running ros-diamondback-turtlebot (or anything, really) on the Eee 1215N

Tags: ros, turtlebot, asus

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We bought an Asus 1215N Eee PC with the intention of rebuilding our Turtlebot on it. Bizarrely, I can't get the default build of Ubuntu 10.04 to work correctly; in particular, the Broadcom wireless NIC and the Atheros Fast Ethernet interface are not supported. Ubuntu (including the kernel) are now up to date with the software update.

After fighting with it, I used a USB stick and my Mac to download the common-wireless drivers. I can build for the Atheros and Broadcom devices, but I can only make one of them work at a time. Once I got FastE working with common-wireless, I tried to install the default Broadcom hardware drivers... that didn't work either. The driver is active but I am unable to connect to any wi-fi network.

Isn't the 1215N the exact machine that Willow Garage is distributing? If so, does anybody know if a) Asus changed the hardware; or b) there's a simple way to get both network interfaces working at the same time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10715/running-ros-diamondback-turtlebot-(or-anything,-really)-on-the-eee-1215n/) by [Alaina](https://answers.ros.org/users/767/alaina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2011-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have updated the ISO to include support for the Asus 1215N-PU27 as well as the 1215N-PU17.  Give it a try with the new version.  [mailing list post](https://kforge.ros.org/pipermail/turtlebot-users/2011-August/000022.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've created an ISO for installing the TurtleBot with the proper drivers for the wireless and ethernet card.. please go to http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/diamondback/Robot%20Setup and follow the instruction steps for installing your Asus 1215N.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-07-26**:
Alaina did you get the ISO to work?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Though we're having no problem with the official ISO, we have received netbooks in the past which despite being identical models purchased at the same time have completely different wireless hardware (some showing the same symptoms you describe).

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2011-07-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1